# How to retrieve a subset of rows from DataFrame based on condition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:

```
edges =
   srcId    dstId    timestamp
   1        4        1346564657
   1        2        1345769687
   2        4        1345769687
   4        1        1345769687
```

```
vertices =
   id   name   s_type
   1    abc    A
   2    def    B
   3    rtf    C
   4    wrr    D
```

I want to get a subset of `vertices` that would include `id` that are not mentioned among `srcId` and `dstId` in `edges`.

This is the expected output:

```
sub_vertices =
   id   name   s_type
   3    rtf    C
```

How can I do it?

```
val sub_vertices = vertices
  .join(edges, col("id") =!= col("srcId") && col("id") =!= col("dstId"), "left")
  .na.fill(0)
  .drop("srcId","dstId", "timestamp")
  .dropDuplicates()
```

This is my current code, but it gives incorrect result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost near, here are few things you need to change

```
val sub_vertices = vertices
  .join(edges, col("id") === col("srcId") || col("id") === col("dstId") , "left")
  .filter($"srcId".isNull && $"dstId".isNull)
  .drop("srcId","dstId", "timestamp")
```

Output:

```
+---+----+------+
|id |name|s_type|
+---+----+------+
|3  |rtf |C     |
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: Which of two approaches would be faster on a large dataset?

Comment: If the set of Ids is able to fit into RAM memory of each worker and driver, then the solution by @ramesh should be faster.

Comment: @ScalaBoy  Yeah, I agree with @wind, if the list of `srcId` and `dstId` can fit in all the workers and driver memory, @Ramesh solution should be faster. If the list doesn't fits in memory, You can get OOM error.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala: In my case, the list may not fit into a memory. Therefore I will select your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can *collect the srdId and dstIds into set* and *broadcast the set* to be *used in filter of vertices dataframe* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//collect all the srdId and dstId from edges dataframe into set and broadcast
val srdIdList = sc.broadcast(edges.select(collect_set("srcId").as("collectSrc"), collect_set("dstId").as("collectDst")).rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Seq[Int]](0) ++ row.getAs[Seq[Int]](1) toSet).collect()(0))

//using udf function remove all the rows that are in collected srdId and dstId in above step
def containsUdf = udf((id: Int) => !srdIdList.value.contains(id))
vertices.filter(containsUdf(col("id"))).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+------+
|id |name|s_type|
+---+----+------+
|3  |rtf |C     |
+---+----+------+
```